# Does the Azure SQL Pricing Tier affect restore speeds?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-sql-database

I've been restoring my databases within Azure SQL Databases so they can be used for testing and I've been wondering if I can speed up this process.

Does the pricing tier of the new database or of the source database have any effect on restore speeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing purposes we always restoring database to Premium RS1 (or higher). Then, if we still need this DB in the future, we are changing it to S0 until new tests.

Restore speed is depended on target pricing tier. Some times ago documetation says (and I can comfirm it from my practice) that restore speed is approximately 50Gb per hour for Standard and 100Gb per hour for Premium tier.

Answer (score 0):

Try scaling to premium tiers prior to restore and scale down after migration has finished.

If you are trying to create a copy of your existent Azure SQL Databases to create test/development environments, use CREATE DATABASE AS COPY OF Transact-SQL.

```
CREATE DATABASE db_copy   
    AS COPY OF ozabzw7545.db_original ( SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'P2' )  ;
```

I suggest you to use [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) to have a copy of your on-premises databases into Azure SQL database.

Comment: Yes, I could try that but I've noticed that the same database can have a wide range of restore times, so I'd have to do some more extensive tests between the tiers to see a significant result. 
So I was hoping to get a definitive answer from someone who has done it (any people from Azure out there? :) ) rather than having to pay a higher Azure bill to experiment. Thanks for the tip about TSQL, that might be faster than the portal.